# Pigeonhole principle: Prove that any (2n+1)-element subset of{1,2, ...,3n}contains three consecutive integers.

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that any (2n+1)-element subset of{1,2, ...,3n}contains three consecutive integers.

My general thinking is that pigeonholes are sets of consecutive integers from {1,2,...,3n} which are {1,2,3}{4,5,6},...,{3n-2,3n-1,3n} and that each one is a pigeonhole filled 2/3 of the way, so the (2n+1)th element would have to fill a pigeonhole fully, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Does this help you? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252816/pigeonhole-principle-prove-that-any-set-of-n1-integers-from-1-2-2n

Comment: Pigeonhole principle states that at least one of your sets will contain $\lceil (2n+1)/n\rceil = 3$ elements from the $(2n+1)$-element subset, and so we are done.

Answer (score 4):

You've got $n$ many holes, $\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}, \ldots,\{3n-2,3n-1,3n\}$.

If you've got $2n+1$ balls to put in them, you cannot have at most $2$ per hole because that only leaves room for at most $2n$ balls, so one hole must contain $3$ and you're done.

So that partition indeed does work.

Comment: And this proves not only that each $(2n+1)$–element subset contains three consecutive numbers, but a stronger fact that it contains a set of three consecutive numbers of the form $\{3k, 3k+1, 3k+3\}$ for some $k\in\{0,1,\dots,(n-1)\}.$